# Тире или запятая в пояснительном обороте

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Возник вопрос по предложению:
Во избежание сбоев при распознавании подписи физлица (?) представителя контрагента с использованием доверенности (?) рекомендуется...
Думаю поставить тире с двух сторон, поскольку оборот кажется пояснительным. Но есть сомнения. Видела похожие конструкции, когда оборот отрывался тире, а закрывался запятой.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться со знаками.

Comment: А может, скобки? В деловом стиле поясняют в скобках.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ставим одно тире и запятую: *Во избежание сбоев / при распознавании подписи **физлица** — **представителя контрагента** / с использованием доверенности, рекомендуется...*

**Пояснение**

**Тире**

Розенталь, пункт 10, примечание (2): если приложение выражает **конкретное значение**, а предшествующее определяемое слово имеет **общее** или образное значение: На совещании министров иностранных дел стран — членов Организации американских государств выступил министр иностранных дел Кубы (Газ.);

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

**Примечания**

(1) Сочетание "физлица — представителя контрагента" в этом случае читается практически **без паузы** в одну фонетическую фразу. Я называю такой знак "тире-дефис", но это не общепринятый термин.

(2) Косая черта обозначает произносительные паузы при чтении.

**Запятая**

Розенталь, http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114

Факультативное обособление распространенного обстоятельственного оборота со своим знаком.

Answer (score 0):

Если перед обособляемым приложением находится тире, то после него может находится запятая только в том случае, если после приложения стоит запятая, как, например, в предложении: ‟Если бы он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор — весы, то понял бы источник ошибки”. [Ссылка на правило (1-й пункт примечания к пункту 10)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111)

В вашем предложении после приложения нет запятой, поэтому обособление тире с двух сторон (но я не совсем понимаю смысл этого предложение и что там к чему относится).